# Why are the articles "an" and "the" not allowed in this structure? "(The/An) X though Y was..."

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, articles

> (***An**) astute businessman *though* he was, P was capable of extreme
> recklessness
>
> (***The**) actual perpetrators *though* they were, the criminals never admitted their guilt in court

Why are the articles not allowed in this structure?

Comment: I sure wish I knew.

Comment: Me too. That's the thing about idioms; not only don't they make sense literally, their rules don't make sense grammatically. The word ***arbitrary*** comes to mind. Repeatedly.

Comment: Try *undoing the inversion*: Though they were **the** actual perpetrators *versus* Though they were actual perpetrators. Ain't the same thing. And I do not agree with the first, necessarily. If you uninvert it, it requires *an*. Though he was an actual businessman. So...It's an editor's choice.

Comment: Who says the articles are 'not allowed'? I would have thought the second one needed it, if the criminals were _the perpetrators_ of a particular crime. It's a clumsily-worded sentence anyway.

Comment: @KateBunting I kind of agree in the sense that, without the article, the second sentence sounds as if the criminals were mere general perpetrators, rather than perpetrators of the crime in question, which doesn't make a lot of sense, given the context.  But adding a "The" to this construction strikes me as awkward/non-idiomatic, so you probably would just avoid the construction altogether.  So, I agree with the premise of the question that articles are not allowed.

Comment: @cruthers - As I said, it's clumsily worded and I wouldn't have expressed it that way.

Comment: How about substituting _though_ for _as_ ?

Comment: You *mean*: How about substituting **as** for **though**.

Comment: @Lambie You may not believe it, but I was waiting for it: only using **with/by** though? not **for**?  "(transitive, formerly proscribed, in "substitute X **with/by** Y");  to replace X with Y.
_I had to substitute old parts with the new ones_" https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/substitute#Verb

Comment: You had the word **though**, right? You want to now use the word **as**, right? ***Ergo***, **there is only one way to say this using the verb substitute in active voice**: To substitute **as** for **though**. The with/by thing is a red herring. Use those if you like. But **my point** is about the **order of what exists and what is replacing it**. Not the prepositions.

Comment: Order depends on preposition.  Substitute A for B = Substitute B with A.

Comment: I'm looking for an adjective: **Astute** though he was *as a businessman*, P was capable of extreme recklessness.

Comment: @Lambie what about _Astute a business man as he was,..._ ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130010/discussion-on-question-by-gjc-an-astute-businessman-though-he-was-the).

Comment: Who said they are not?  It sounds fine to me.

Comment: I prefer the inverted versions for both:
Although he was an astute businessman, Even though they [had admitted to me, that they] were the actual criminals, they never admitted their[or that] guilt in court.

Comment: Could you possibly say what the evidence is that in each of these examples the/an article is literally not allowed?  I have got some way through the process of searching for evidence in the Oxford English Grammar, but no luck so far.  'Zero article' is confined to 'count' versus 'non-count' nouns'.  Does CGEL have anything to say on the subject?  Or are we left with intuition?  I have my own notion of what is is going on, but if I set it out I shall be offering a suggested answer as a comment:  I can't use the 'answer' box because it is opinion-, not evidence-based.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me the examples you have presented are cases of the 'zero article'.

If the noun is countable and plural (e.g.., "research studies") or uncountable (e.g., "information") and it is being used in a nonspecific or generic way, no article is used.

Here are some more specifics:

No article is used when a plural countable noun is generic or nonspecific.

- I bought new pens and pencils at the store. (general, not specific ones)
- Cats have big eyes that can see in the dark. (cats in general, all of them)
- Babies cry a lot. (babies in general, all of them)

{Notice that an article does not appear before 'pens', 'pencils', 'Cats' or 'Babies'.}

No article is used when a noncount noun is generic or nonspecific.

- I bought milk and rice at the store. (generic reference)
- We were assigned homework in this class. (generic reference)
- There has been previous research on the topic. (generic reference)

{Notice that an article does not appear before 'milk', 'rice', 'homework' or 'research'.

[Reference: Walden University]

I hope this helps.

Comment: The work by Master on both  zero and null articles (qv) is worth reading. He claims that the missing articles in 'We had Ø₁ chicken for tea' and 'He was crowned Ø₂ King' are very different entities. OP's examples would be analysed as using the zero and null articles respectively (note which overt articles they are 'replacing').

Comment: he notion 'countable/uncountable' is problematic.  However, I share your intuition that the usages in question have something to do with using the nouns in question attributively/adjectivally (not far from your 'generic'.  The trouble is finding the evidence:  so far I have been unable to find evidence one way or the other in the Oxford English grammar.  "zero article" only deals with countability.  Could the usage have arisen mundanely:  nobody noticed the dropping of articles in these contexts - it just caught on: not allowed/allowed but standard/non-standard.